# Configuring GPU for NetTrain

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, gpu

I currently have access to a system with two GPUs:
GeForce GTX 1080 and Tesla K40c

I would like to use this machine for training neural networks in Mathematica.

When using the option `Target Device->"GPU"` for `NetTrain` it automatically chooses the GTX 1080 GPU for training (I can monitor this from the commandline using nvidia-smi).

However, this card doesn't work with Mathematica yet. It starts training but the loss quickly goes to zero. It's a common problem; see: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/917616

I would like to know how I can fix this issue or configure `NetTrain` to use the other GPU (Tesla K40c).

More details:

`$Version -> 11.0.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (September 21, 2016)`

Comment: `Target Device->{"GPU",1}`

Comment: @AlexeyGolyshev Why don't you write an answer?  I wouldn't have found this solution.

Comment: @AlexeyGolyshev Thanks a lot! It worked. Now I will be getting access to a few P100 GPUs soon. Do you know how I can train using multiple GPUs simultaneously? Is it `TargetDevice->{"GPU",{1,2,3}}`

Comment: @dan7geo I don't know. I have only one NVIDIA card. :-)

Comment: @AlexeyGolyshev Guess I'll have to post another question when I do get those cards :)

Comment: @dan7geo I have updated my answer with a note that numeration of GPUs starts from 0. You should know if you will experiment with multi-GPU configuration.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Solution**

```
"TargetDevice"->{"GPU",1}
```

It should be noted that numeration of GPUs starts from 0.

`"TargetDevice"->"GPU"` is equivalent to `"TargetDevice"->{"GPU",0}`

**UPDATE**

In Mathematica 11.1 numeration of GPUs starts from 1.

Comment: @"Alexy Golyshev" What about `"TargetDevice"-> {"GPU", All}` for multigpu training (which mxnet supports)

Comment: @user5601 Multi-GPU training support will be in 11.1+ ([presentation](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jeh98c7dqk58s9o/AABm9L3HwQn6sz0sQPHoCIbna?dl=0&preview=4-NeuralNets.nb), slide 19; [source](https://www.wolfram.com/events/cvpr-2016-tutorials/))

Comment: @AlexeyGolyshev You might want to update this answer. Seems like in 11.1 the numbering starts from 1. 'TargetDevice should be either "CPU" or "GPU", or {"GPU", n} for multi-GPU systems, where n is a positive integer that specifies which system GPU to use.'