# How to import a Tensorflow model?

Tags: import, machine-learning, neural-networks

I've trained a network in Tensorflow and have the checkpoint files, I'd like to if anyone has written a parser or importer to pull the evaluation graph and/or weights into Mathematica?

Comment: MMA uses MXNet under the hood.  So effectively need to be able to convert TensorFlow model into MXNet model which can then be loaded into MMA.  I do not think such a tool exists at the moment to convert between those two frameworks.  Checkout the [DL model convertor](https://github.com/ysh329/deep-learning-model-convertor) page on GitHub.

Answer (score 5):

In [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132022/configuring-gpu-for-nettrain),I find [this notebook](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jeh98c7dqk58s9o/AABm9L3HwQn6sz0sQPHoCIbna?dl=0&preview=4-NeuralNets.nb).

And it tells us:

[image]

***PS:In [this website(Deep Learning - The Straight Dope)](https://github.com/zackchase/mxnet-the-straight-dope),I find MXNet will support some converters***

[image]

So in the future,Tensorflow model -> MXNet model -> **then importing to Mathematica**

Comment: But I found it contains nothing more than this title.