# Classify/NetTrain run indefinitely without output when using GPU

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, gpu

I am experimenting with Mathematica's Classify/NetTrain functions for the first time.
When I don't set a TargetDevice option, Mathematica defaults to the CPU and everything works as expected.
When I specify "TargetDevice"->"GPU" and run the same code, the kernel runs the code seemingly indefinitely and I can't interrupt the process without quitting the kernel.

I do get this error whenever I use function using "NeuralNetwork" for the first time:

```
General::newmxnet: An unexpected condition happened: a neural network runtime of the wrong version was loaded. This might lead to unexpected problems. Please contact Wolfram Research.
```

afaik, all my GPU drivers are up to date and I have tried running functions with and without loading the CudaLink package.

The code I am using is pretty straight forward, I don't think the problem is there, but I'll post it anyway in case it is:

This works:

```
Classify[
    trainingset,
    Method -> "NeuralNetwork"
 ]

Classify[
     trainingset,
     Method -> "NeuralNetwork",
     TargetDevice -> "CPU"
     ]
```

This does not:

```
Classify[
     trainingset,
     Method -> "NeuralNetwork",
     TargetDevice -> "GPU"
     ]
```

I hope someone can help me out.

EDIT:
After letting the NetTrain function run for multiple hours, the process finally exits with the following error code:

```
NetTrain::arrdiv: Training was stopped early because one or more trainable parameters of the net diverged. The net with the lowest validation loss will be returned. To avoid divergence, ensure that the training data has been normalized to have zero mean and unit variance. You can also try specifying a lower learning rate, or use a different optimization method; the (possibly automatic) values used were Method->{ADAM,Beta1->0.9,Beta2->0.999,Epsilon->1/100000,GradientClipping->None,L2Regularization->None,LearningRate->Automatic,LearningRateSchedule->None,WeightClipping->None}, LearningRate->0.001. Alternatively, you can use the "GradientClipping" option to Method to bound the magnitude of gradients during training.
```

Comment: There is example in Tutorials `n = 10000;
trainingData = RandomReal[1, {n, 4}] -> RandomChoice[{1, 2, 3}, n];
AbsoluteTiming[classifier =  Classify[trainingData, Method -> "NeuralNetwork", 
   TargetDevice -> "GPU"]]` . I run it and it works in v12.0. But first time we need to restart session since it upload package from the server.

Comment: Also this example works with v.12.2 but in both versions  `Classify[]` with option `TargetDevice ->"CPU"` runs faster.

Comment: I get the same behaviour with your example. Restarting the session does not work for my own code though. I don't think reloading the session every time I want to train is a viable option either way..

Comment: Did you seen this post https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132022/configuring-gpu-for-nettrain?rq=1 ?

Comment: I saw that question. I don't think it's related.

Comment: Did you got `True` on evaluation  `Needs["CUDALink`"]
CUDAQ[]` ? Some errors depend on combination `$System, $Version` and license type as well. Also you can ask support from the Wolfram Research stuff on   https://community.wolfram.com/ .

Comment: I did get the True on that evaluation. I have contacted support. They have told me they are going to release a new paclet soon that may solve my problems. I hope it comes out soon and it does solve them.